# How many pairwise disjoint, totally disconnected, dense subsets does $\mathbb{R}$ have (in the standard topology)?

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: How many pairwise disjoint, totally disconnected, dense subsets does $\mathbb{R}$ have (in the standard topology)?**

This is how I did it. I am not sure whether this is correct or not. I know that I have the idea but cant say positively whether this will work or not.

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $p \notin \mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $p \in \mathbb{Q^{C}}$. Then, let us consider 2 open sets $S$ and $T$, such that $S = \mathbb{Q} \cup$ {p} and $T = \mathbb{Q^{C}}$ \ {p}. Then, both $S$ and $T$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, $S \cap T$ = $\emptyset$, i.e. $S$ and $T$ are disjoint. Then, I guess we can show that $S$ and $T$ are both totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ as above. I can say that $(S,T)$ is a pair, such that $S$ and $T$ are disjoint and both are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and disconnected. But I am not sure what arguments and reasoning to show in order to establish this statement.

Since, $p \in \mathbb{Q^{C}}$ is arbitrary and $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$ is infinite, therefore we can construct infinitely many of such pairs.

Can someone help me on this and show explicitly? Appreciate your help and support on this.

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn’t ask for disjoint **pairs** of totally disconnected dense subsets of $\Bbb R$: it asks how big a collection of **pairwise disjoint** totally disconnected dense subsets of $\Bbb R$ can be. If $\mathscr{D}$ is a family of sets, $\mathscr{D}$ is **pairwise disjoint** if $D\cap E=\varnothing$ whenever $D,E\in\mathscr{D}$ and $D\ne E$, i.e., if no two members of $\mathscr{D}$ intersect.

HINT: For each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $x+\Bbb Q=\{x+q:q\in\Bbb Q\}$. It’s not hard to show that each of these sets is totally disconnected and dense in $\Bbb R$. You can also show that for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$,

- $x+\Bbb Q=y+\Bbb Q$ iff $x-y\in\Bbb Q$, and
- if $x+\Bbb Q\ne y+\Bbb Q$, then $(x+\Bbb Q)\cap(y+\Bbb Q)=\varnothing$.

Now consider $\mathscr{D}=\{x+\Bbb Q:x\in\Bbb R\}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of size continuum of pairwise disjoint totally disconnected and dense subset of $\Bbb R$: let $B$ be a base for the vector space $\Bbb R$ over the field $\Bbb Q$ (using Zorn here, or any of its equivalents), then $|B|=\mathfrak{c}$ and $\{\{x+q: q \in \Bbb Q\}: x \in B\}$ is the required collection, as can easily be checked.